# Wordpress - Displaying login form in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I tried the wordpress stack but no luck so thought I'd try here...

So I am trying to display a working version of the default wordpress login form on one of my pages. There is code in the functions.php file that creates the shortcode and as far as I know it works successfully, however after submitting the form, it simply refreshes the page and doesn't redirect to the url I am specifying...can anyone see why it might not work as it should?

This is the function I put in the functions.php file:

```
//Login form Shortcode
add_shortcode( 'login-form', 'my_login_form_shortcode' );
/**
 * Displays a login form.
 *
 * @since 0.1.0
 * @uses wp_login_form() Displays the login form.
 */
function my_login_form_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $defaults = array(      "redirect"              =>  site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )
                        );

        extract(shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts));
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $content = wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false, 'redirect' => $redirect ) );
        }
    return $content;
}
```

I am then placing it in the desired page like so:

```
[login-form redirect="https://myurl.com"]
```

but instead of redirecting me to the right page, it is instead refreshing the page even though I am now successfully logged in...any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a solution to your code but have you tried the Theme My Login plugin (available on Wordpress Plugin directory)? I've used it successfully on a few sites and it does a really good job of handling custom login pages (including redirects after logging in) as well as signup pages, reset password pages and it also gives users front end access to edit their user profile. You can turn these features on and off as well to cherry pick exactly what you want. At the time of writing this, it's been updated 4 weeks ago so the developer is very active with the plugin.

Comment: @AdamJB thanks for that. Yes I did try it but wanted a simple solution which basically mirrors the wp login form on to a different page

Comment: Have you tried this approach in a template file for the page?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

Comment: @AdamJB hmmmm I will give it a shot

Comment: Here's another good tutorial that may help: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/08/30/adding-a-login-form-to-a-page  It seems to be a slightly different approach to the one you took in your code.

Comment: @AdamJB thanks for that. I am gonna take a look at tml as well and see

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add this code below

```
add_action( 'login_form_middle', 'add_lost_password_link' );
function add_lost_password_link() {
    return '<a href="/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Forgot Your Password?</a>';
}

if(!function_exists('vivid_login_page'))
{
  function vivid_login_page()
  {
      $args = array(
        'echo'           => true,
        'remember'       => true,
        'redirect'       => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        'form_id'        => 'loginform',
        'id_username'    => 'user_login',
        'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email Address' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
        'value_username' => '',
        'value_remember' => false
    );
    wp_login_form($args);
    add_lost_password_link();
  }
  add_shortcode('vivid-login-page', 'vivid_login_page');
}
```